# How to add each items in a loop?

Tags: c#, loops

> this is my controller/back-end code, Im trying to add each answer and store it in one container.

```
for each (var prov in provs)
    {
        SpesGraduate x = new SpesGraduate();
        x.Province = prov.Province;
        x.yr1_TotalGrad = placed2.Where(plc => plc.POID == prov.ID).Count();
        x.yr1_ColTechvocGrad = placed2.Where(plc => plc.POID == prov.ID && (plc.GradEduc == "Tech-Voc" || plc.GradEduc == "College")).Count();
        x.yr1_PercentGrad = 0;
        x.yr2_TotalGrad = placed.Where(plc => plc.POID == prov.ID).Count();

        double answer;
        if (x.yr2_TotalGrad == 0 && x.yr1_TotalGrad == 0)
        {
            answer = 0;
        }
        else if (x.yr2_TotalGrad == x.yr1_TotalGrad)
        {
            answer = 100;
        }
        else if (x.yr1_TotalGrad == 0 && x.yr2_TotalGrad != 0)
        {
            answer = x.yr2_TotalGrad * 100;
        }
        else if (x.yr1_TotalGrad != 0 && x.yr2_TotalGrad == 0)
        {
            answer = x.yr2_TotalGrad * -100;
        }
        else
        {
            double increase = (x.yr2_TotalGrad - x.yr1_TotalGrad);
            answer = (increase / x.yr1_TotalGrad) * 100;
        }
        
        //this is where I try to do it hoping to make this possible in a for-loop statement.

        x.yr2_Percentage = answer;
        double total = 0;
        double temp1;
        double temp2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            temp1 = x.yr2_Percentage;
            total = temp1 + temp2;
        }
        ViewBag.TotalPercent = total; //> This is where I store the answer.
        Graduates.Add(x);
    }
```

> I want here to store each number and add them in a container to show it on my table. I didn't show the code in my table because i think it is not necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by `container` what it is? Could you please share more details and your requirement? `ViewBag.TotalPercent = total;`  What do you want to do here?

Comment: Did you mean you want to add each item from loop to a variable then list of item want to bind here `ViewBag.TotalPercent = total`? Share your full cotroller code for quick assistance.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron yes sir

Comment: what im  thinking is how to add the each "answer" in my foreach statement

Comment: Share details of `provs`  what issue you aree having with?